# OnCreateOptionsMenu not called after updating code to AndroidX

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I recently updated my Xamarin.Android project to AndroidX code. In my fragment, `OnCreateOptionsMenu` would get called, but it is not called anymore after changing my fragment to `AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment`. I would call `SetHasOptionsMenu(true)` but that method does not exist anymore. So I try this in my `OnCreateView` instead:

```
View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.my_layout, container, false);
AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = view.FindViewById<AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.drawerToolbar);
(this.Activity as AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AppCompatActivity).SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
var actionBar = (this.Activity as AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AppCompatActivity).SupportActionBar;
if(actionBar != null)
{
    actionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}
```

`actionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled` gets called but my override of `OnCreateOptionsMenu` is still not called.

```
public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    // never get called
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the fragment that he has a menu.

```
HasOptionsMenu = true
```

Comment: `setHasOptionsMenu` does not exist in `AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment`

Comment: I admit that I am not exactly sure how Xamarin handles deprecated methods but it is [there](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean))

Comment: It's been changed to a property in Xamarin `HasOptionsMenu = true` if you change this to your answer I will accept it